# VLookUp not returning from formula

Tags: excel

I am very new to the excel scene and wrote a Vlookup formula that I am pretty sure is correct. It references a formula instead of a value and it only gives me N/A. When I type the value of the cell and reference that instead it works properly.

Here is the original formula

=VLOOKUP(C4,H5:K10,3,FALSE)

Comment: Well, show us what you have typed and the data you are working with, then we may be able to help.

Comment: It might be considered important to see the formula as well as some semblance of the data.

Comment: Sorry for not putting the formula. I am new but I can see how this could have made the process easier. I will make sure I always am clear and concise. @tdj thank you that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the formula that you are using is returning values as text. This is a common question for those who are new to excel/VLOOKUP. I would try to use

=VLOOKUP(INT(A2),B6:D9,2,FALSE)

The INT() function should return it as a function and cause it to work.

Hopefully, you understand the rest of the logic for vlookup, I used the cell references merely as examples. Next time, it might be good to include the formula in the question for clarity purposes. If you need any more help let me know!